# Passing (grouped) keyword args to wrapped functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, functional-programming, arguments, decorator

I have a class which wraps a collection of functions so as to be called later:

```
class Wrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, *funcs):
        self.funcs = funcs

    def callFuncs(self, *args):
        # call each function with its respective arguments
```

In order to make sure that the args provided are paired correctly, I specify that the arguments must be grouped in tuples for each argument. No arguments gets an empty tuple. Thus if we have `foo(a)` and `bar(b)` and `bork()`, and we construct a `Wrapper` like so:

```
wrapper = Wrapper(foo, bork, bar)
```

Then we would use `callFuncs()` like so:

```
wrapper.callFuncs((a,),(),(b,))
```

Simple enough, I can handle that. I'd probably use [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)s so I can iterate over each tuple and fill the arguments in. I think this would even work for variable args. But what about keyword args?

```
>>> def mytest(*args, **kwargs):
...     print args, kwargs
... 
>>> mytest((1,),(),(bar=3))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    mytest((1,),(),(bar=3))
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I specify the keywords for these arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something along these lines:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, *funcs):
        self.funcs = funcs
    def call_funcs(self, *args):
        for func, args in zip(self.funcs, args):
            func(*args[0], **args[1])

def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'foo(args={}, kwargs={})'.format(args, kwargs)

def bar(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'bar(args={}, kwargs={})'.format(args, kwargs)

def baz(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'baz(args={}, kwargs={})'.format(args, kwargs)

def bork(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'bork(args={}, kwargs={})'.format(args, kwargs)

wrapper = Wrapper(foo, bar, baz, bork)
wrapper.call_funcs(((), {}), ((1,), {}), ((), {'spam':3}), ((42,), {'dent':17}))
print

# to make using it easier and nicer looking, optionally include this:
params = lambda *args, **kwargs: (args, kwargs)

# then the same thing can be written:
wrapper.call_funcs(params(), params(1), params(spam=3), params(42, dent=17))
```

Output:

```
foo(args=(), kwargs={})
bar(args=(1,), kwargs={})
baz(args=(), kwargs={'spam': 3})
bork(args=(42,), kwargs={'dent': 17})

foo(args=(), kwargs={})
bar(args=(1,), kwargs={})
baz(args=(), kwargs={'spam': 3})
bork(args=(42,), kwargs={'dent': 17})
```

Comment: Pretty ingenious! But, won't I have to change my function signatures, as well as some implementation (e.g. with `foo(a)` becoming `foo(*args)` doing `a = args[0]` at the beginning to compensate)? I'll take it if it's my best option, though.

Comment: As long as the functions' signatures matches what you pass each one, I don't think you'll need to modify them. I gave all the example functions both `args` and `kwargs` only make it possible for them to print out everything that had been passed in the call.

Comment: All right, very cool. I think this involves minor compromise on my interface (I wanted it to look the same as when you pass arguments normally), but it makes things pretty simple for me to implement.

Comment: See update to my answer for something that might help with your interface.

Comment: Very, very nice. I wish I could upvote your answer twice for that.

Comment: Thanks! Note that using the added syntactic-sugar will entail some additional overhead...

Answer (score 1):

```
mytest((1,),(),dict(bar=3))
```

should work fine

Comment: All right, now that I have that `dict` representing they keyword args, how can I use that to specify keyword args in `partials`? The doc shows that you do something like this: `basetwo = partial(int, base=2)`.

Comment: After looking at @martineau's answer I realize that I could use `**` to work with that `dict`, thanks a bunch for the builtin!